# How to force the user to always keep only one cell selected?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to force the user to always keep only one cell selected in Google Sheets?

I tried to create a script with the onSelectionChange event, but in all tests when I select a range I can't force the selection to be active only in the first upper left cell of the range.

My intention is to prevent the user from selecting a range and accidentally deleting or changing cells with formulas. I will make the spreadsheet available to someone else, and not share, so the native range protection feature is useless, as at most I can put an alert message in the range, but it does not prevent the user from deleting or changing the protected range.
I've already got efficient ways to protect cells with formulas since the change or the delete started from a single cell selection, now I need to prevent the selection scenario of a range.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(); 
if (sheet == "MySheet") { 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().activate()
}
}
```

I just find it bad that Google Sheets fluctuates a lot in trigger response time. Sometimes it runs immediately, sometimes it takes one to three seconds to run.